# How should I go about making game menus that I want to fit inside a container?

Tags: menu, xna, submenu

I have to write an XNA game for a project in my college program.  I'm making a turn-based RPG in the vein of the Gameboy Pokemon games.  I'd like to align the menu options with a container at the bottom of the screen, with never more than 4 options.  This should give you a rough idea about how I want the combat screen to look:

[image: Pokemon Battle Image]

I currently have a menu system that aligns all the menu items with the center of the screen, meaning menus end up looking like this:

Start Game
Options
Quit

but in the center of the screen.

What is the best way to position the menu items in a similar fashion to the image above? Should I hardcode in the positions for the menu items, should I try and make some kind of class to act as the container for these items and have their position be relative to the size and position of the container, or use some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to hardcode the positions it could get pretty complex, depending on how much flexibility you want.

I would create a container class which is part of a tree structure, (see [scene graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph)), with a parent container and a list of child containers. That is the most common way of handling relative positioning. Here a quick example:

```
public class Container
{
    public Container Parent { get; set; }

    public List<Container> Children { get; set; }

    public Vector2 RelativePosition { get; set; }

    public Vector2 AbsolutePosition
    {
        get
        {
            // The container is the root node
            if (Parent == null)

                return RelativePosition;

            else

                return RelativePosition + Parent.AbsolutePosition;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need even more flexibilty you could create a floated layout, where the elements are positioned dynamically depending on their size.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Lucius, creating a Container class is the best solution.
Currently I'm developing an UI application for the XBox.

Therefor I needed something like a positioning engine, with everything being relative, so I didn't need to calculate pixel stuff everytime.

What I did was creating a Container class, which contains roughly following attributes:

```
 VectorTopLeft (Which the element which contains a Container object uses for drawing)
 VectorTopRight
 VectorBottomLeft
 VectorBottomRight

 Align (Enum: Right, Center, Left)
 VerticalAlign (Enum: Top, Middle, Bottom)
 NewRow (bool)
 PreviousContainer (Container)
 ParentContainer (Container)
 Width (Getter)
 Height (Getter)
 PercentageHeight (getter/setter) (Percentage of the height of the parent container)
 PercentageWidth (getter/setter) (Percentage of the width of the parent container)
 PixelHeight (getter/setter) (Absolute height in pixels)
 PixelWidth (getter/setter) (Absolute width in pixels)
 AspectRatio: Used for setting the width to a ratio of the height, usefull for different screen aspects (4/3 or 16/9 for example)

  MarginLeft
  MarginRight
  MarginTop
  MarginBottom
```

The following vectors include margins, these are vectors used by the alignment procedure.

```
 AbsoluteVectorTopLeft
 AbsoluteVectorTopRight
 AbsoluteVectorBottomLeft
 AbsoluteVectorBottomRight
```

The following size attributes also include margins, usefull for calculating remaining sizes

```
  AbsoluteWidth (getter)
  AbsoluteHeight (getter)
```

And then some flags which get set to true if something crucial changes, and vectors/size stuff needs to be recalculated.

The alignment stuff is pretty complex, as in the fact that it uses recursion, and also calls previous container functions to shift everything to the right place.

The newrow attribute tells the system that it needs to start the element at a new row in the parent container, and is used for keeping the vertical alignment in mind.

The system might have some minor flaws, but at this moment it works as a charm for all my GUI related positioning stuff, and it works pretty damn fast!